# How to use json-data in SWIFT for iOS 9

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, ios9

I get data from a json-file:

The json-data looks like:

```
{
  "Datum": "2015-06-05 16:55:55",
  "Tagesauftraege": {
       "Wasserschaden": {
       "sieben": "97",
       "gestern": "138",
       "heute": "18"
   },
   "Leckortung": {
       "sieben": "54",
       "gestern": "72",
       "heute": "11"
    }
  },
  "Umsatz": {
       "db1": "74000",
       "oel": "44200"
  }
}
```

Now i would

```
@IBAction func buttonRefreshData(sender: UIButton) {
    let jsonUrl = url

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! [String: AnyObject]

            self.labelWasserschadenSieben.text = //String(jsonData['Tagesauftraege']['Wasserschaden']['sieben'])

        } catch _ {
            // Error
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

But I got the error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Tagesauftraege'

I know, it's not PHP, but in PHP i got a easy to used array. How is it in SWIFT? How can i use Print all my data easy to labels like the labelWasserschadenSieben ?

This is the Output when i make print(jsonData)

```
["Datum": 2015-06-05 16:55:55, "Tagesauftraege": {
Leckortung =     {
    gestern = 72;
    heute = 11;
    sieben = 54;
};
Wasserschaden =     {
    gestern = 138;
    heute = 18;
    sieben = 97;
};
}, "Umsatz": {
db1 = 74000;
oel = 44200;
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the basics. JSON can be a dictionary or an array or nil, so you get an AnyObject? You can assign it to an NSDictionary with as? or as!. You then have a dictionary. From that dictionary you can read the key "Tagesauftraege" which again could be a dictionary, array, string, number, null, or nil. So you get an AnyObject? And then you go on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Double quotes for strings in swift

```
self.labelWasserschadenSieben.text = String(jsonData["Tagesauftraege"]["Wasserschaden"]["sieben"])
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i got this error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: I would say instead of casting to NSDictionary cast it to [String: AnyObject] so ```as! [String: AnyObject]```

Comment: i changed let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! [String: AnyObject] but i got the Error:  Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Can you tell me what type the jsonData is coming back as?

Comment: Right i just figured the problem its a classic pyramid of ddom situation in swift, it unwraps the data for "Tagesauftraege" key which will be an any object Type which does not have subscripting to fix this you would have to cast this to [Sting: AnyObject] then repeat...this framework will make this parsing proccess a whole lot easier.....https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON